# Rules help: After updating existing content

Tags: 7, rules

First time using Rules to make a complicated rule. Would appreciate some help. I'm making rules to send an e-mail, to a pre-defined e-mail address, after an existing node is updated. This node is of a certain type, and this type has a taxonomy term reference field. When any node of this type gets updated, by a user with certain role, Drupal should send an e-mail, and in the e-mail it should attach the **name** of the taxonomy term.

tl;dr/problem: What I'm having trouble is, when creating a condition to check the user's role (the user who updated the content, not the author). There seems to be only the "Author" of the node available on the Data selector (see attached image). Is `node:author` the correct one to check for the user who updated the content?

[image: user data selector]

Comment: There seems to be a "site:current-user" selector as well. Is this the correct one? I'm not sure how reliable this is when multiple users are logged in to the system?

Comment: Yes, it is `site:current-user`. Everything is OK with multiple logged in users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your task you need `site:current-user` token which corresponds to `$GLOBALS['user']` (`global $user`) object.

> I'm not sure how reliable this is when multiple users are logged in to the system?

Webserver creates new PHP thread (or process) for each request so there are no sharing variables between requests.`global $user` variable is initialized by Drupal on every request.

When you have just updated a node you can use `global $user` to know who updated this node. At any time after updating you can get that user id from revision (`$node->revision_uid`).